# How can i get it to return the names instead of numbers?

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and I'm sorry the code is bad, I'm trying to get the "rollFruits" method to return a random name from the "fruits" list but its returning numbers instead. how can I get it to return the names?

Its returning numbers instead of names

```
class devilFruit
{
    public string name;
    public int price;

    public devilFruit(string _name, int _price)
    {
        name = _name;
        price = _price;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Devil Fruit Rolling Text Game";
        Random randomfruit = new Random();
        devilFruit gomu = new devilFruit("GomuGomu No Mi", 650000);
        devilFruit bomu = new devilFruit("BomuBomu No Mi", 500000);
        devilFruit bara = new devilFruit("BaraBara No Mi", 550000);
        devilFruit sube = new devilFruit("SubeSube no Mi", 400000);
        devilFruit kiro = new devilFruit("KiroKiro no Mi", 440000);
        devilFruit Hana = new devilFruit("HanaHana no Mi", 700000);
        devilFruit kage = new devilFruit("KageKage no Mi", 750000);
        List<string> fruits = new List<string>();

        void rollFruit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(randomfruit.Next(0, fruits.Count));
        }
        
        fruits.Add(gomu.name);
        fruits.Add(bomu.name);
        fruits.Add(bara.name);
        fruits.Add(sube.name);
        fruits.Add(kiro.name);
        fruits.Add(Hana.name);
        fruits.Add(kage.name);
        rollFruit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show what you tried.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(fruits[randomfruit.Next(0, fruits.Count)]);`

Answer (score 2):

To return the fruit, you need to use the randomly generated index for the `fruits` array. Also the whole code can be made simpler. Check it out

```
class DevilFruit
{
    public string name;
    public int price;

    public DevilFruit(string _name, int _price)
    {
        name = _name;
        price = _price;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Devil Fruit Rolling Text Game";
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        List<DevilFruit> fruits = new List<DevilFruit> {
            new DevilFruit("GomuGomu No Mi", 650000),
            new DevilFruit("BomuBomu No Mi", 500000),
            new DevilFruit("BaraBara No Mi", 550000),
            new DevilFruit("SubeSube no Mi", 400000),
            new DevilFruit("KiroKiro no Mi", 440000),
            new DevilFruit("HanaHana no Mi", 700000),
            new DevilFruit("KageKage no Mi", 750000)
        };

        DevilFruit randomFruit = rollFruit(fruits, randomGenerator);
        Console.WriteLine(randomFruit.name);
    }
    
    private static DevilFruit rollFruit(List<DevilFruit> fruits, Random random)
    {
        return fruits[random.Next(0, fruits.Count)];
    }
}
```

Comment: this did not work

Comment: How exactly? Please give the error messages

Comment: Nice refactoring. I would also change the names to Pascal case to match .NET Naming conventions

Answer (score 0):

```
    void rollFruit()
    {
        var randomFruit = fruits[randomfruit.Next(0, fruits.Count)];
        Console.WriteLine(randomFruit.Name + ": " + randomFruit.Price);
    }
```

Comment: this broke my code

Comment: @vircobb what didn't work?